# Including Roles and Queues in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I've inadvertently included Roles and Queues into our managed package through deploying with the force.com migration tool. I made a managed package from this and it looked like those metadata were included but they are not listed in the packaged components.

Are there special managed packaging rules for these types of metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think they are part of the package. AFAIK you cannot package roles.

They are not listed as available:

[Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)

Items referencing queues and roles also cannot be included in a managed package

> References to a specific user in workflow actions, such as the email recipient of a workflow email alert, are replaced by the user installing the package. Workflow actions referencing roles, public groups, account team, opportunity team, or case team roles may not be uploaded

and for queues

> List views associated with queues cannot be included in a package

[Special Behavior of Components in Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm)

So I do not believe that they are able to be in your managed package

Comment: Actually we were able to package queues, just not through package web UI, but purely using ant and package xml approach.